# How to show resticted values in "not_in" in laravel Validator?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this validation rules in laravel:

```
$validator = Validator::make($model, [
    "role"=>"in:admin,manager,writer"   
],[
    "in"=>"selected :attribute is invalide"
]);
```

now I want to show some things like this message when the user selects an invalid role:

"Role must be one of this values: admin, manager, writer"

how can I reference to this values by placeholder such as **:attribute** or **:max**. I try **:in** but this is not working.

Comment: Have you tried `:other` ?

Comment: In case it doesn't work, my best bet would be extending validation somehow, or just add a parameter to the validation message in `./project/resources/lang/**/validation` and then when returning that error, replace your parameter with the values you need

Comment: I find the solution which is ":values".

Comment: ahh okay, these messages should be better documentated